# sailsjs not picking local updated json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sails.js

[image]

In this sailsjs app we are not using any database. There is multiple json files in  folder in data folder ( you can see it in root level).
Inside controller we are accessing like

```
req.session.categories = require(require('path').resolve('data/catInfo.json'));
```

catInfo.json is updated through some cron job twice a day. Issue is sailsjs not picking up updated data but if i restart the server then it is picking up new data. somewhere it is storing old json and serve that old json.

What i had already checked :

```
1. try new browser / incognito browser. so this is not a session issue.
2. data folder is not under assets folder. so it is not going under .tmp folder.
```

Then where the old data is being stored ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules included with `require` are cached, that means JSON files too.

If the file is being updated then you'll need to read it using the `fs` module.

```
req.session.categories = 
    JSON.parse(
        require('fs').readFileSync(require('path').resolve('data/catInfo.json'))
    );
```